# Return XSLT in mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xslt

I want return XSLT format in mvc what is the mime type for this?

```
 public FileResult DownloadTemplate(string templateCode)
    {
        try
        {
            var template = _manager.GetTemplateByCode(templateCode);
            const string fileName = "Template";
            return File(template.Value, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text/xsl` for that purpose:

```
public FileResult DownloadTemplate(string templateCode)
{
    try
    {
        var template = _manager.GetTemplateByCode(templateCode);
        const string fileName = "Template";
        return File(template.Value, "text/xsl", fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `File` helper's signature is

```
FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)
```

This should be enough info to answer your question.